# Import existing terraform deployment into Google Cloud Infrastructure Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

GCP launched Infra Manager, a managed service to deploy infrastructure defined using Terraform into Google Cloud.

I've been deploying Terraform from my machine (so I have a local .tfstate) and I would like to migrate to Infra Manager; but all guides I found, do the initial deployment using Infra Manager (this is, upload your config and do a new deployment)

I would like to import my terraform configuration AND current tfstate into Infra Manager and deploy from there.

Infra manager has the [ability to import an existing statefile](https://cloud.google.com/infrastructure-manager/docs/state-file) (create a new deployment, lock deployment, import state file, unlock deployment).

I created a new, 1 resource deployment, and tried to import my big tfstate but the last step fails and I cannot unlock the deployment:

```
% gcloud alpha infra-manager deployments describe projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/deployments/XXX
createTime: '2023-11-03T22:18:03.269740935Z'
latestRevision: projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/deployments/XXX/revisions/r-0
lockState: UNLOCK_FAILED
name: projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/deployments/XXX
serviceAccount: projects/XXX/serviceAccounts/gcp-infra-manager@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
state: FAILED
stateDetail: 'Invalid resource state for "projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/deployments/XXX":
  Deployment "projects/XXX/locations/us-central1/deployments/XXX" is already
  locked'
terraformBlueprint:
  gcsSource: gs://XXX-tmp/terraform/
updateTime: '2023-11-03T22:31:08.162102603Z'
```

Nevertheless, I don't think this is the best way to import an existing deployment. Any hints?